# Brandoo Wordpress for SQL Server

Tags: wordpress

We are a small company and we will soon launch a site based on Wordpress. Since we already are using SQL Server for our other sites we are thinking about maybe using Brandoo Wordpress which let you use SQL Server instead of MySQL for Wordpress.
But I noticed that their version of WP is a fork of version 3.6. So its not updated since 2013-10-16.
Its almost one year old.
I have mailed Brandoo and asked if they plan any update soon but I havent received any answer.

My questions :
1. Do you think its safe to use Brandoo even that it is one year old?
2. Do you think the abstraction layer they have built to translate Mysql to MSSQL can itself harden the protection for SQL injections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little opinion-based, but...

You should really be keeping WordPress as up-to-date as possible.  Security patches are released very, *very* regularly, and you'll want to implement these ASAP; this is one of the reasons WordPress does core updates automatically.

Most security holes within WordPress come from poorly written themes or plugins (or even malicious themes or plugins), so by writing your own, or using themes or plugins proven to be secure, you minimise your risk - that said, you will still be running an old, and potentially insecure version of WordPress itself.

You are also leaving yourself vulnerable to potential security holes in the future.  Let's say that a major security hole is discovered in the current version of WordPress (currently 4.0), and you need to patch immediately.  Well, you can't, but everyone else can, so you'll be left vulnerable.

I can't speak for your question #2, which asks about hardening protection of the SQL injections.  The DB layer that ships with WordPress prepares statements in a secure manner, that isn't prone to SQL injections, but I'm unsure what Brandoo does - I'd be surprised if SQL injections weren't handled properly.

MySQL itself is free software, is available for Windows and Unix systems, and has a pretty low footprint.  My recommendation would be to install MySQL on your server(s) and use that for this website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will most likely go with MySQL on Windows.

Comment: Good choice, @JohnF :)